# 'NSHashTable' requires that 'any MyCustomProtocolAnyObject' be a class type

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, calendarkit, nshashtable

Curious, why I'm getting this error:

[image]

If I declare that only objects can conform to the protocol:

```
public protocol DayViewStateUpdating: AnyObject {
    func move(from oldDate: Date, to newDate: Date)
}
```

And then trying to instantiate an `NSHashTable`of that protocol:

```
private var clientsHashTable = NSHashTable<DayViewStateUpdating>.weakObjects()
```

I'm getting the error:

> 'NSHashTable' requires that 'any DayViewStateUpdating' be a class type

But the **any DayViewStateUpdating** is guaranteed to be a class type, as it's declared as **AnyObject** earlier. Or am I missing something?

Source code of the file in context: [DayViewState](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/blob/master/Sources/DayViewState.swift)

Comment: Why are you using `NSHashTable` in Swift?

Comment: `.weakObjects` option

Comment: I see. There might be a better alternative in Swift but I don't know. Marking your protocol as `@objc` should fix it I think. See also [why protocols don't conform to protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/5133585).

Comment: Actually declaring protocol as `@objc` makes it compile. Might not be the best solution, but on the other hand, the clients are all `UIKit`-compatible, so they're subclasses of `NSObject`. So this solution should work well.
Sometimes there is no need to look for a pure-Swift solution, language is just an tool and there is no point of hiding from `NSObject` in a `UIKit`-based UI framework :) Please, answer the question, so that I could mark your answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSHashTable` is expecting Objective-C style protocols, rather than Swift-style protocol existentials.

Marking your protocol as `@objc protocol DayViewStateUpdating` works.

But really, you can get away without needing `NSHashTable` here, by using a `Weak` wrapper like so:

```swift
public struct Weak<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var object: T?
    
    init(_ object: T) { self.object = object }
}

private var clientsHashTable = [Key: Weak<DayViewStateUpdating>]
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but the question was specifically about the `NSHashTable`. I knew about this method as well. I'm interested in hiding the wrapper behavior.

Comment: @RichardTopchii Ah interesting. Have you explored wrapping Dictionary in its own struct that does/undoes the `Weak` wrapping?

Comment: That is essentially one of the solution (i.e. using a custom data structure), but the question was still about the `NSHashTable` as I was exploring that data structure

Comment: Well `@objc` is the solution there. Has your question been answered?

Comment: Yes :) I'll mark yours then, since it kinda also has that part in it?